# Why I got Exception "403 Repository access blocked'' using pygithub?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-api

I'm trying to scrapy github users' favorite programming language through pygithub,but so strange,every time I want to scrapy user--ELLIOTTCABLE' reposity i got following Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gf/KuaiPan/code/Python/Data Mining/test.py", line 14, in <module>
repo = user.get_repo(j)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/github/NamedUser.py", line 449, in get_repo
"/repos/" + self.login + "/" + name
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 169, in requestJsonAndCheck
return self.__check(*self.requestJson(verb, url, parameters, headers, input, cnx))
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 177, in __check
raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
github.GithubException.GithubException: 403 {'message': 'Repository access blocked', 'block': {'reason': 'unavailable', 'created_at': '2014-01-31T14:32:14-08:00'}}
```

My python code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from github import Github


ACCESS_TOKEN = 'my credential'
client = Github(ACCESS_TOKEN, per_page=100)
user = client.get_user('ELLIOTTCABLE')
repo_list = [repo.name for repo in user.get_repos() if not repo.fork]
print(repo_list)

for j in repo_list:
    repo = user.get_repo(j)
    lang = repo.language
    print(j,':',lang)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***403 HTTP Status*** denotes a forbidden request, thus you have provided credentials that can't let you access some endpoints.

So you may need to provide a valid credentials (*username / password*) when creating the `Github` object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from github import Github

ACCESS_USERNAME = 'username'
ACCESS_PWD = "password"
client = Github(ACCESS_USERNAME, ACCESS_PWD, per_page=100)
user = client.get_user('ELLIOTTCABLE')
repo_list = [repo.name for repo in user.get_repos() if not repo.fork]
print(repo_list)

for j in repo_list:
    repo = user.get_repo(j)
    lang = repo.language
    print(j,':',lang)
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: I did it just the way you described above, but after 50 repos it throws exactly the same error. Can it be a reason of too many requests via the API?

Comment: Maybe it could be, didn't reach such a limit personaly.